# Jquery if statement inside .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get some jQuery running replacing the html of an object. But how can i put an if statement inside, like this.

```
$(this).html("<select id=\'status\' name=\'status[]\' multiple><option value=\'1\'"+if(string_contains(selected, 1)) { document.write(\' SELECTED\'); }+"></option></select>");
```

The if statement makes it stop working.

And a little side question.

Why cant i break inside the .html like this:

```
        $(this).html("
<select id=\'status\' name=\'status[]\' multiple>
<option value=\'1\'"+if(string_contains(selected, 1)) { document.write(\' SELECTED\'); }+"></option>
</select>");
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow line breaks inside string constants (yet).

Comment: @Pointy: Unless you escape it with a backslash, at least.

Comment: You are looking for the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?

Comment: @Bergi right; and even then it's not supported by all interpreters I don't think. I personally don't think that's a good idea as the handling of start-of-line whitespace is problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got is just syntactically incorrect.

```
$(this).html("<select id=\'status\' name=\'status[]\' multiple><option value=\'1\'" +
  (string_contains(selected, 1) ? "\' SELECTED\'" : "") +
  "></option></select>"
);
```

The `if` statement is just that — a **statement**. It doesn't work as part of a JavaScript expression. However, the `? :` operator will do what you want. It takes the form:

```
query ? expr1 : expr2
```

The `query` expression is evaluated. If the result is "truthy", the overall result is the value of `expr1`; otherwise, it's the value of `expr2`. The operator precedence of `? :` is pretty low so it's generally a good idea to parenthesize the whole thing.

Comment: I did try this

$(this).html("<select id=\'status\' name=\'status[]\' multiple><option value=\'1\'" +(selected.indexOf(1) ? "\' SELECTED\'" : "") +"></option></select>");

It doesnt work at all.

However

$(this).html("<h1>TEST</h1>");

works just fine.

Comment: @NikolajSvendsen well when you say "doesn't work at all" - is a JavaScript error reported? Is the result incorrect?

Comment: It says that selected.indexOf is not a function

Comment: @NikolajSvendsen What is the value of "selected"?  For "indexOf" to work, it has to be an array or a string.

Comment: var selected = $(this).data("selected");

Which contains "1,5,7,2"

Comment: Well if the value of "selected" were really "1,5,7,2" it would work. The error you described means that whatever "selected" refers to, there's no "indexOf" property to be found or else it's something other than a function (unlikely). If the value is the *array* `[1, 5, 7, 2]` and you're testing in Internet Explorer 8 or older, then that browser does not have "indexOf" for arrays.

Comment: I found the solution on this link http://lookfirst.com/2011/12/dont-use-jquery-data-method-use-attr.html

Comment: @NikolajSvendsen using ".attr()" instead of ".data()" would be a somewhat risky thing to do - Internet Explorer can leak memory from attributes with JavaScript object values.